# Mac CLI curl - commands not found?

Tags: curl, bots, command-line-interface

I'm searching a wordpress multisite set up for some possible SEO spam and I'm using the command line to curl with Mozilla but for some reason it's not working.

```
curl -A “Mozilla/4.0 \(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0\)” http://blogs.mysite.com | grep “http://www.gncc.ge/”

curl –user-agent “Mozilla/4.0 \(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0\)” http://blogs.mysite.com | grep “http://www.gncc.ge/”
```

I've looked through a couple of tutorials to makes sure I was doing everything right but I either get nothing back or I get these errors.

I get these errors though

```
-bash: MSIE: command not found
-bash: Windows: command not found
```

Should these compatibility mentions not be included? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using curly quotes or straight quotes?

I see:

```
$ url -A “Mozilla/4.0 \(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0\)” http://blogs.mysite.com | grep “http://www.gncc.ge/”
```

And not:

```
$ url -A "Mozilla/4.0 \(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0\)" http://blogs.mysite.com | grep "http://www.gncc.ge/"
```

If you are using curly quotes, it can explain your issues. Curly quotes have no special meaning is the shell. Regular quotes keep the parameter from being divided by whitespace. Curly quotes do nothing of the sort.

Don't use TextEdit to edit command shell scripts. Get a ***real*** program editor. [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) is free. It's the *little brother* to BBEdit.

Another one to try is [TextMate](http://macromates.com), but it's not free.

Of course, you can always use Xcode which is free and comes with a full IDE environment. Or, learn Emacs or VIM which come on the Mac.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I have text wrangle and should have used that but now it seems that it is giving me an error in that it could not resolve host: –user-agent; nodename nor servname provided same with Mozilla

Comment: It should be two dashes in front of `--user-agent` and not `-user-agent`. Also make sure it's an ASCI dash and not an em or en dash.

Answer (score 0):

Might need to escape your semicolons (That's what I had to do on cygwin):

```
curl –user-agent “Mozilla/4.0 \(compatible\; MSIE 6.0\; Windows NT 5.0\)” http://blogs.mysite.com | grep “http://www.gncc.ge/”
```